# When does the addItemToOrder pipeline get called?

Tags: atg

While adding an item to the cart, the highlevel flow of method call is -

handleAddItemToOrder() -> addItemToOrder() -> mergeItemInputForAdd() -> doAddItemToOrder -> runProcessRepriceOrder() -> runProcessAddItemToOrder().

The chainId for this last pipeline is defined in CartModifierFormHandler.addItemToOrderChainId as per oracle documention. Now I have few questions on execution of this last pipeline -

1. What does this pipeline do? There is no details provided for this in documentation.
2. There is another component PurchaseProcessHelper which contains the same method runProcessAddItemToOrder(). Is this the method which gets called when an item is added to cart? If yes, then how does the control flows to this method.

Please help me in understating this. (Please provide relative se-up in configuration files of CartModifierFromHandler and PurchaseProcessHelper)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What does this pipeline do? There is no details provided for this in documentation.

Nothing by default, because `CartModifierFormHandler.addItemToOrderChainId` by default it is set to `null`, so no pipeline will run.

Go to your local /dyn/admin, and view the service configuration for CartModifierFormHandler. (http://HOSTNAME:PORT/dyn/admin/nucleus/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler/?propertyName=serviceConfiguration) Here you will see that the property value for `addItemToOrderChainId` has been commented out:

```
#addItemToOrderChainId=addItemToOrder
```

Why has it been commented out? Take a look at the `PipelineManager`:

```
<!-- These items are commented out because by default we do not need to run any chains <pipelinechain name="addItemToOrder" transaction="TX_REQUIRED" headlink="???"></pipelinechain><pipelinechain name="setOrder" transaction="TX_REQUIRED" headlink="???"></pipelinechain> -->
```

By default, there are no chains to run, but with some implementations, you may care to do so, or you may just want to customize the component class for the `CartModifierFormHandler` service.

> 2. There is another component PurchaseProcessHelper which contains the same method runProcessAddItemToOrder(). Is this the method which gets called when an item is added to cart? If yes, then how does the control flows to this method.

Once again, by default this method does not invoke a pipeline chain, because `PurchaseProcessHelper.addItemToOrderChainId` has been set to `null`. When is the method invoked? It is not invoked by the `CartModifierFormHandler` adds an item to the order. I believe it is simply a convenience method to be used by other form handlers that need to add an item to the cart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. Whatever you have mentioned is correct, but in my application I can see following set-up:
In CartModifierFormHandler.peoperties file -  addItemToOrderChainId=addItemToOrder

In PurchaseProcessHelper.properties file - 
addItemToOrderChainId=processProductDetailsUpdate


In commercepipline.xml file, there is a pipeline chain named processProductDetailsUpdate.. While there is nothing by name addItemToOrder. Can you please clarify this how are these connected?